# Invoke two different controls at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I am creating a Form and try to show as a modal, providing a parent.

```
Form modal = new Form();
modal.ShowModal(OtherForm);
```

The problem is that they are accessed from different threads and raise exceptions. I'm trying to use invoke following "the microsoft way", that means using delegates. However I have two controls `modal` and `OtherForm` that need to be invoked at the same time. If I invoke only one of them, I'll get exception that the other one was accessed from a different thread and vice-versa.

The code below is **mockup** solution which leads to stack overflow due to invoke loop. How this can be solved?

```
public static void ShowModalForm(Form f, Control parent)
{
    if (parent.InvokeRequired || f.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ShowModalFormCallback d = new ShowModalFormCallback(ShowModalForm);
        f.Invoke(d, new object[] { f, parent });
        parent.Invoke(d, new object[] { f, parent });
    }
    else
    {
        f.ShowDialog(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to invoke them at the same time, don't make them modal. A modal control by definition doesn't allow access to the rest of the application.

Comment: You should also use .BeginInvoke instead of .Invoke when using this pattern.  Using .Invoke can sometimes lead to deadlocks depending on what the UI thread is currently doing.

Comment: Right. It'll try to use some better pattern according to this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired . This invoking in winforms has really becamse pain in the ass. Every single UI interaction must go through this invoking stuff. Why can't it just be handled by .net

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing, but this might work?

```
public static void ShowModalForm(Form f, Control parent)
{
    if (parent.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ShowModalFormCallback d = new ShowModalFormCallback(ShowModalForm);
        parent.Invoke(d, new object[] { f, parent });
    }
    else
    {
        f.ShowDialog(parent);
    }
}
```

But I really don't understand what you're trying to do. And does f really reference an existing instantiation of a Form object?

Comment: This will not work. It will raise cross-thread exception for `f`. Yes `f` is existing instance.

Comment: If both f and parent are correctly instantiated on the UI thread then it is only necessary to do InvokeRequired on one of them. If InvokeRequired says false, then you are on the UI thread and should not be getting cross-thread exceptions.

Comment: Sorry. `parent` was created in the main UI thread whereas `f` was not. Still, your solution should work right? `f.ShowDialog()` should execute in `parent`'s thread. Still, it complains that `f.ShowDialog()` is accessed in different thread that it was created. Well. If the idea is to do all winforms actions in main UI thread then in theory I cannot create any winforms outside UI thread?

Comment: Also I could delegate `f` to be created in main UI thread but how would I access it later from this other thread? delegates do not return any values.

Comment: I don't think you're thinking correctly about what is going on. Try to mentally substitute "AmIOnWrongThread" for "InvokeRequired". InvokeRequired is not actually associated with the control that you apply it to - it can be any old control, as long as all of your controls/forms are correctly instantiated on the UI thread.

Comment: I found solution to my problem thanks to you. Indeed I was confusing two things. I voted up your answer since it's solution to my post although problem lied somewhere else. That is to say, I was creating a form from a thread other than UI thread. I thought delegates can't return values and hence I won't be able to access this form after delegating it to the main thread.